Nginx not proxying https requests
There is a nginx proxy server running on 0.0.0.0:80. The configuration is very simple:
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    server {
        listen 80;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://$host;
        }
        
    }
}

When I use it to proxy(using the proxy protocol) an http request it works fine. F.e.
curl http://www.google.com -x 0.0.0.0:80
When I am trying to proxy an https request however f.e.
curl https://www.google.com -x 0.0.0.0:80
nginx returns the following error:
 29#29: *1 client sent invalid request while reading client request line, client: 192.168.65.1, server: , request: "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
While curl returns this:
CONNECT tunnel failed, response 400
What am I doing wrong? Is it because I am trying to initially connect via http to the proxy server and then use https?
